# how to make more buttons in java GUI swing

Tags: java, swing

I would like to use the java swing to make two buttons, one that add +25 to 100, the initial value, and one other that adds +10 to 100, always the initial value:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GUI implements ActionListener {
    private int button1 = 100;
    private int button2 = 100;
    private JLabel label;
    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel panel;
    
    
    public GUI() {
        
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
        // Bottone & etichetta per il player 1
        JButton button = new JButton("add 25");
        panel1.add(button);
        button.addActionListener(this);
        label = new JLabel("initial value: 100");
        panel1.add(label);
        // Bottone & etichetta per il player 1
        JButton button1 = new JButton("add 10");
        panel2.add(button1);
        button1.addActionListener(this);
        label = new JLabel("initial value: 100");
        panel1.add(label);
        
        
        // Impostazioni della finestra
        panel1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(30, 30, 10, 30));
        panel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
    
        frame.add(panel1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("GUI");
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        // Impostazioni della finestra
     }  
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            new GUI();
       
        
    }
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            button1 = button1 + 25;
             label.setText("Value: " + button1);
        }
        public void actionPerformed2(ActionEvent e) {
            button2 = button2 + 10;
            label.setText("Value: " + button2);
        }
    
}
```

as you can see it should create two buttons, this is what I receive as output at first:

```
(button) add 25
(label) initial value: 100
(label) initial value: 100
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MSHz.png]

and after I click it, it just adds 25 to the first one:

```
(button) add 25
(label) initial value: 125
(label) initial value: 100
```

Comment: *and after I click it, it just adds 25 to the first one:* - that is exactly what the code in the ActionListener does.

Comment: The stack trace tells you what the error is and the statement causing the error. So determine which statement is causing the problem and then fix the problem. We don't have that information so we can't help.

Comment: Ok but it should add 10 to the second one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating a Swing GUI, it's a really good idea to separate your data model from the GUI view.  This separation makes it easier to code the model and easier to code the view.  The controller updates the model, which in turn updates the view.

Here's a GUI I whipped up to illustrate this model / view / controller pattern.

[image: Increment GUI]

The first thing I did was define some fields and an array.

```
private int[] values;

private int startValue;
private int currentValue;
```

The `startValue` is the starting value (100), the `currentValue` is the current value (205 in the picture), and `values` is an `int` array that holds the values 10 and 25.

Here's the code that sets these values.  I set these values in the constructor of the class, so they're set before anything else happens.

```
public IncrementGUI() {
    this.startValue = 100;
    this.currentValue = startValue;
    this.values = new int[] { 10, 25 };
}
```

Since I put the values in an `int` array, if I want to add another value, all I have to do is add the value to the `values` array.

Now that we have the model built, let's start on the view.  This is my main method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            IncrementGUI inc = new IncrementGUI();
            inc.createJFrame();
        }
    });
}
```

I call the `SwingUtilities` `invokeLater` method to ensure that the Swing components I create and execute are created and executed on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).  This keeps us from having threading problems with the GUI.

When I instantiate the class, the model fields are set in the constructor, then the GUI is created.

Here's the method I wrote to create the JFrame.

```
private void createJFrame() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Increment Value");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    
    frame.add(createValuePanel(), 
            BorderLayout.BEFORE_FIRST_LINE);
    frame.add(createButtonPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

The JFrame methods have to be called in a specific order.  This is the order that I use for most of my Swing applications.

The `setDefaultCloseOperation` method allows me to close the application when the X button in the upper right is left-clicked.  The `pack` method takes the Swing components and "packs" them into the smallest possible `JFrame` consistent with the size of the Swing components.  The `setLocationByPlatform` method sets the location of the `JFrame` on the screen consistent with the platform operating system.  Finally, the `setVisible` method makes the `JFrame` visible.

We created two `JPanels`, one to hold the "Value" `JLabel` and `JTextField`, and the other to hold the `JButtons`.  We do this because I want to use two different [Swing layout managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) to layout the Swing components.

The `JFrame` has a `BorderLayout` by default.  I placed the value `JPanel` before the first line (on top) and the button `JPanel` in the center.

Next, I coded the details of the value `JPanel` in the `createValuePanel` method.

```
private JPanel createValuePanel() {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Value: ");
    panel.add(label);
    
    valueField = new JTextField(10);
    valueField.setEditable(false);
    setValueField(currentValue);
    panel.add(valueField);
    
    return panel;
}

public void setValueField(int value) {
    valueField.setText(NF.format(value));
}
```

I used a `JTextField` to hold the current value.  I made it non-editable, so the user cannot change the value.

I wrote the `setValueField` method as a separate method because we're going to use this method in the `actionPerformed` method of the `ActionListener`.

We use a `FlowLayout` because I want the Swing components to flow from left to right.

Next, I coded the details of the button `JPanel` in the `createButtonPanel` method.

```
private JPanel createButtonPanel() {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 5, 5));
    panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    
    for (int index = 0; index < values.length; index++) {
        JButton button = new JButton("Add " + values[index]);
        button.addActionListener(this);
        button.setActionCommand(Integer.toString(values[index]));
        panel.add(button);
    }
    
    return panel;
}
```

I used a `GridLayout` to hold a single column of the `JButtons`.  I put some empty space around the `JButtons` with an empty border to make the GUI more visually appealing.

Because I create the `JButtons` in a for loop, I create as many `JButtons` as there are values in the `values` array.  This way, when you add a value to the `values` array, a new JButton will be created.

A `JButton` can hold an action command `String` as well as display text.  We use this action command `String` to pass the increment value to the `actionPerformed` method.

Finally, I coded the `actionPerformed` method.  It's pretty simple.  I get the increment value from the `JButton`, increment the current value, and display the current value in the `JTextField`.

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    int value = Integer.valueOf(event.getActionCommand());
    currentValue += value;
    setValueField(currentValue);
}
```

Here's the entire runnable example.  I hope this explanation helps you to create more complex Swing GUIs.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class IncrementGUI implements ActionListener {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                IncrementGUI inc = new IncrementGUI();
                inc.createJFrame();
            }
        });
    }
    
    private static NumberFormat NF = 
            NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance();
    
    private int[] values;
    
    private int startValue;
    private int currentValue;
    
    private JTextField valueField;
    
    public IncrementGUI() {
        this.startValue = 100;
        this.currentValue = startValue;
        this.values = new int[] { 10, 25 };
    }
    
    private void createJFrame() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Increment Value");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        frame.add(createValuePanel(), 
                BorderLayout.BEFORE_FIRST_LINE);
        frame.add(createButtonPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    private JPanel createValuePanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Value: ");
        panel.add(label);
        
        valueField = new JTextField(10);
        valueField.setEditable(false);
        setValueField(currentValue);
        panel.add(valueField);
        
        return panel;
    }
    
    public void setValueField(int value) {
        valueField.setText(NF.format(value));
    }
    
    private JPanel createButtonPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 5, 5));
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        
        for (int index = 0; index < values.length; index++) {
            JButton button = new JButton("Add " + values[index]);
            button.addActionListener(this);
            button.setActionCommand(Integer.toString(values[index]));
            panel.add(button);
        }
        
        return panel;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        int value = Integer.valueOf(event.getActionCommand());
        currentValue += value;
        setValueField(currentValue);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't add panel2 to your JFrame, altough I would suggest just putting both buttons on one JPanel.

Comment: I also receive the  java.lang.NullPointerException error

Comment: Please paste your stack trace into your original question, so it can be analyzed!

Comment: Sorry but the stack trace is the same, I just said that I receive an error, maybe I didn't understand the question

Comment: The stacktrace is the error message you get from your compiler. Please paste this here or into your original question to help me diagnose your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
private int button1 = 100;
...

public GUI() 
{
    ...
    JButton button1 = new JButton("add 10");
```

Don't use the same variable name in your class. It is extremely confusing to have a local variable and instance variable with the same name. A variable name should be descriptive.
So maybe you have variables like:

```
private int value10 = 100;
...

public GUI() 
{
    ...
    JButton button10 = new JButton("add 10");
```

to indicate that the button10 button is used to increment the value of value10.

> but it should add 10 to the second one

```
public void actionPerformed2(ActionEvent e) {
```

You can't just make up a method by adding a "2" to the end of the method name. That code will never be invoked. If you have two buttons, then you need two ActionListeners.

The easiest way to do this is to use a lamda:

```
button25.addActionListener((e) ->
{
    value25 += 25;
    label.setText("Value: " + value25);
}

button10.addActionListener((e) ->
{
    value10 += 10;
    label.setText("Value: " + value10);
}
```

Comment: @Gilbert Le Blanc Thank you very much for this explanation, I understood many things now. How could I make sure that after the user clicks at least two times the button another button appears? is this possible to do?

Comment: @user14430653: I'm not sure what you're asking.  Do you want to add buttons after the user has started playing?