# How can I clear my text fields, combo boxes and radio buttons in java swing?

Tags: java, swing

**Register Button**

```
@Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == Register) {
                String x = txt6.getText();
                String t = txt4.getText();
                String z = "@";
                String y = "gmail.com";
                String w = "0302-";
                String data1 = txt1.getText();
                String pass2 = String.valueOf(pass.getPassword());
                if (data1.equalsIgnoreCase("Isha") && pass2.equalsIgnoreCase("1234")) {
                    if (x.contains(z) && x.contains(y) && t.contains(w)) {
                        if (b.isSelected()) {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Login Successfully");
                        } else {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid, Try Again");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

**Reset Button**

This is the code that I am using for the reset button but it doesn't clear my text fields, combo boxes and radio buttons when I click it.

```
  else if (e.getSource() == Reset){
            txt1.setText(" ");
            txt2.setText(" ");
            txt4.setText(" ");
            txt5.setText(" ");
            txt6.setText(" ");
            pass.setText(" ");
            b.setSelected(false);
            City1.setSelectedIndex(0);
            showpassy.setSelected(false);
        }
```

**Show Password CheckBox**

```
if (e.getSource() == showpassy) {
            if (showpassy.isSelected()) {
                pass.setEchoChar((char) 0);
            } else {
                pass.setEchoChar('*');
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure your code is executed? Can you show the entire `ActionListener`? Or try to use debugger.

Comment: KunLun , i've edited my code you can check it again. This is the overall code for ActionListener.

Comment: Each button should have its own ActionListener. You should NOT be using if/else statements to check which button is clicked. To proved if your code is executed all you need to do is add a `System.out.println(...)` statement. The posted code doesn't help because we have no idea what the rest of your code does or if you even add an ActionListener to the button. Post a proper [mre] demonstrating a problem. So create a frame with a single component and a "Reset" button. Get that working first and then add back in other components.

Comment: camickr , but in ActionListener there is only one actionPerformed method is available. Please guide me properly i am beginner of java.

Comment: Most people would use a lamda to easily create a unique ActonListner.  For a simple example check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64304509/how-to-make-more-buttons-in-java-gui-swing/64307866#64307866